# When I try to boot into windows 10 it boots into Ubuntu UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows

I have installed ubuntu as second OS in my computer with dual boot. Ubuntu works perfect, but when I try to get into windows it just takes me to ubuntu grub again, doesn't matter if i'm selecting the option in the grub, in the uefi menu or into the bios it just boots ubuntu grub. I can access to all my windows files and folders from ubuntu and it is all there. My efi partition is on /dev/sda1

I tried boot-repair application with the recommended option and that doesn't work either. I've looked through a lot of forums but I couldn't find an answer to this. I have also updated the grub and nothing. I hope you can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in the same BIOS or UEFI mode Windows is installed in? If Windows is installed UEFI and Ubuntu is installed BIOS, GRUB will not boot Windows.

Comment: How can I check that? And it is not only grub, It's uefi menu and bios too. I'm very sure ubuntu is inistalled in UEFI, but windows I'm not too sure. Windows installation it's just next, next, next.

Comment: google "is Windows UEFI mode"

Comment: yeah, both are UEFI